# Understanding Time and Space Complexity of Networkx function in python with relation to system configuration

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, time-complexity, networkx, space-complexity

I am trying to find all the cycles in my data using networkx.simple_cycles() function in python. As written in networkx documentation "**This is a non-recursive, iterator/generator version of Johnson’s algorithm**". Johnson's algorithm has a time complexity of: **((nodes+edges)*(cycles+1))** and space complexity of: **(nodes+edges)**.

I have created a directed graph from transaction data with edges as **From node--->To node**. I am removing the nodes which have in-degree or out-degree of 0 as they will not contribute to cycles(elementary circuits).
My graph details after removing the in-degree and out-degree 0 nodes are as follows:

For 1.09 million records:

```
Number of nodes remaining-39278;
Number of edges-26324;
Number of cycles- Not able to get any output as the code keeps on running.
```

For 1.08 million records:

```
Number of nodes remaining-38664;
Number of edges-25710;
Number of cycles- 5612438.
```

For 1.05 million records:

```
Number of nodes remaining-36737;
Number of edges-23784;
Number of cycles- 69671.
```

For 1.01 million records:

```
Number of nodes remaining-34393;
Number of edges-21566;
Number of cycles- 3079.
```

For 1 million records:

```
Number of nodes remaining-33841;
Number of edges-21125;
Number of cycles- 3072.
```

I want to understand the relation of time and space complexity with system configuration. Given all these details about an algorithm, how can i find out what system configuration will be suitable for a particular size of data. Why am i not able to run this algorithm beyond 1.08 million data?

My system configuration:
AMD PRO A12-8800B (2.1 GHz, up to 3.4 GHz, 2MB Cache, 4 Cores) with AMD Radeon R7 Graphics.
8GB RAM.

Comment: (With some limited/outdated graph-theory experience) Your numbers indicate some exponential blow-up in the number of cycles. The algorithmic complexity consists of the term ```n_cycles```, where the number of cycles can grow exponentially (without assumptions about your data/graphs) and therefore your algorithm grows exponentially too in general. As this is highly dependent on the data/graphs (again indicated by your numbers) there is not much theory to help you here (given the setting) as there should exist cases, which you won't be able to compute just consisting of 1000 records too.

Comment: going from 1.01 to 1.05 million you multiplied the number of cycles by about 20.  Going from 1.05 million to 1.08 it was multiplied by about 80.  It's growing even faster than exponentially.  I don't have a good guess for how many cycles you'll have at 1.09 million, but it'll be huge.  Your run time is proportional to the number of cycles (and the number of edges/nodes also matters).

Comment: @sascha I also want to understand the relationship between algorithm complexity and system configuration as i have already mentioned in my question. How are these two related? Any lead(articles/blogs/research papers) will be helpful.

Comment: Algorithmic complexity is a theoretical tool and does often not help to plan computation-resources (worst-case often not the relevant thing; constants hidden). Your example is one of the more problematic cases, but there are many others (e.g. Simplex).

Comment: Should you not exclude nodes that have in-degree < 1 AND out-degree < 1? With 30k edges, 20k nodes, clearly, most edges connect two otherwise isolated nodes.